Parse two arrays to make one PHP
I have two arrays
Array 1:
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Copy of Carnegie Page' (length=21)
      'keywords' => string 'Master Of Business Administration - Professional' (length=48)
      'description' => string 'Master Of Business Administration - Professional' (length=48)
      'metadata_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/carnegie-copy' (length=38)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Display Name Used in Link Text' (length=30)
      'keywords' => string 'SEO Food' (length=8)
      'description' => string 'SEO TIPS: Meta descriptions should be no more than 150-160 characters. Include the important keywords at the front of the meta description. Do not duplicate meta descriptions for each of your pages. These show up in Search Engine Results Pages and should include a CTA to help visitors choose your page to get the information they are seeking. ' (length=344)
      'metadata_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/program-template2' (length=42)
  2 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'program' (length=7)
      'keywords' => string 'blkah, blahj, blah' (length=18)
      'description' => string 'blah blah blah' (length=14)
      'metadata_id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/program' (length=32)

Array 2:
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'page_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'value' => string '100% Online' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'page_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'value' => string 'Undergraduate' (length=13)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'page_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'value' => string 'Undergraduate' (length=13)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'page_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'value' => string 'Micro-credentials' (length=17)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'page_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'value' => string 'Certificates' (length=12)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'page_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'value' => string 'Undergraduate' (length=13)

I am trying to get the "value" of the second array when the "page_id" matches in both arrays
I have tried nested for loops with if statements to try and filter while using array_push and array_merge/ array_merge_recursive
foreach ($metadata_custom as $meta)
{
    $testarray[] = array( $meta['page_id'] => $meta['value'] );
}

foreach ($metadata as $data)
{
    $i = $data["page_id"];

    foreach ($testarray as $array)
    {
        if( array_key_exists($i, $array))
        {
            $newArray[] = array_merge_recursive(array("value" => $array[$i]), $data);
        }
    }
}

The output i get is close, but instead of adding the "values" key it will just duplicate the element like so.
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'value' => string '100% Online' (length=11)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Copy of Carnegie Page' (length=21)
      'keywords' => string 'Master Of Business Administration - Professional' (length=48)
      'description' => string 'Master Of Business Administration - Professional' (length=48)
      'metadata_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/carnegie-copy' (length=38)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'value' => string 'Undergraduate' (length=13)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Copy of Carnegie Page' (length=21)
      'keywords' => string 'Master Of Business Administration - Professional' (length=48)
      'description' => string 'Master Of Business Administration - Professional' (length=48)
      'metadata_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/carnegie-copy' (length=38)
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      'value' => string 'Undergraduate' (length=13)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Display Name Used in Link Text' (length=30)
      'keywords' => string 'SEO Food' (length=8)
      'description' => string 'SEO TIPS: Meta descriptions should be no more than 150-160 characters. Include the important keywords at the front of the meta description. Do not duplicate meta descriptions for each of your pages. These show up in Search Engine Results Pages and should include a CTA to help visitors choose your page to get the information they are seeking. ' (length=344)
      'metadata_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/program-template2' (length=42)
  3 => 
    array (size=8)
      'value' => string 'Micro-credentials' (length=17)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Display Name Used in Link Text' (length=30)
      'keywords' => string 'SEO Food' (length=8)
      'description' => string 'SEO TIPS: Meta descriptions should be no more than 150-160 characters. Include the important keywords at the front of the meta description. Do not duplicate meta descriptions for each of your pages. These show up in Search Engine Results Pages and should include a CTA to help visitors choose your page to get the information they are seeking. ' (length=344)
      'metadata_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/program-template2' (length=42)
  4 => 
    array (size=8)
      'value' => string 'Certificates' (length=12)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'program' (length=7)
      'keywords' => string 'blkah, blahj, blah' (length=18)
      'description' => string 'blah blah blah' (length=14)
      'metadata_id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/program' (length=32)
  5 => 
    array (size=8)
      'value' => string 'Undergraduate' (length=13)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'program' (length=7)
      'keywords' => string 'blkah, blahj, blah' (length=18)
      'description' => string 'blah blah blah' (length=14)
      'metadata_id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/program' (length=32)

What I want it to look like is:
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'value' => 
           [0] =>string '100% Online' (length=11)
           [1] =>string 'Undergraduate' (length=13)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Copy of Carnegie Page' (length=21)
      'keywords' => string 'Master Of Business Administration - Professional' (length=48)
      'description' => string 'Master Of Business Administration - Professional' (length=48)
      'metadata_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'page_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'ucomm-test-site/programs/carnegie-copy' (length=38)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Which arrays are $metadata_custom and $metadata?

Where are you getting these arrays from? Presumably a database? Makes more sense to just do a join there.

Anyway I think this does what you want: foreach ($array1 as &$one) $one['value'] = array_column(array_filter($array2, fn($v) => $v['page_id'] === $one['page_id']), 'value');

https://3v4l.org/vVdWB

I would solve it this way: https://3v4l.org/oSRIC  (this is not presented in the dupe target from miken22.  I'll see if I can find a better target.)

This looks pretty relevant: Merge 2d array into another 2d array based on a column and create a subarray from related data in another column and Push rows from a 2d array into new subarrays of another 2d array based on a shared column value

First convert Array 1 to an associative array that uses page_id as the key, and add empty value arrays to each item.
$temparray = [];
foreach ($metadata_custom as $item) {
    $item['value'] = [];
    $temparray[$item['page_id']] = $item;
}

Then loop through Array 2, pushing the values onto the corresponding element's value keys.
foreach ($metadata as $item) {
    $temparray[$item['page_id']][] = $item['value'];
}


I had the arrays mixed up but I think this will get me where I need. Thanks!
